# Is there a kind of uniqueness of Poincaré duality?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

There is a related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261929/how-to-calculate-the-cup-product-of-etale-cohomology-to-prove-that-in-poincare-d). I would like to know if there is a more intrinsical way to show this. I want to know if we can get this through the uniqueness of Poincaré duality or the comparison between étale/complex topology, which are not mentioned in that answer.

We have already known that there is a group isomorphism $E[m]\simeq \ker(\operatorname{Pic}^{0}(E)\rightarrow \operatorname{Pic}^{0}(E))\simeq H^{1}_{ét}(E,\mu_{m})$.

I want to ask if

1. there is a kind of uniqueness of nondegenerate pairing?
2. or maybe there is a comparison theorem for Poincaré duality of the normal cases and the étale cases.

Then, we can compute in the complex case which is easier.

If the ellptic curve $E$ is over $\mathbb{C}$, we can choose a isomorphism $E\simeq \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$. Then, we can obtain a group isomorphism $E[m]\simeq H_{1}(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda,\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ (singular homology). The computation for cup product usually shows that if let $\alpha,\beta\in H_{1}(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda,\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ are generators, then for any $m=m_1 \alpha+m_2\beta$, $n=n_1\alpha+n_2\beta\in H_1(\mathbb{C}/\Lambda,\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ we have
$$m\cup n=(m_1n_2-n_1m_2)\alpha\cup \beta,$$
which agrees with the definition of Weil pairing.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: How is that other answer not intrinsic enough? How would a more intrinsic approach look like? I find your requirement a bit vague.

Comment: @AlexM. I want to know if we can get this through the uniqueness of Poincaré duality or the comparison between étale/complex topology, which are not mentioned in that answer.

Comment: In this case, wait some more to see if your question gets reopened, and if it doesn't then edit it and clarify what you mean by "more intrinsic", adding the explanation that you gave me. When reading your question I felt a bit lost, not understanding precisely what it was attempting to do.